# AS3 listen for keypress, but global

Tags: actionscript-3, events, focus

When I add a keypress eventlistener to the stage, it does not fire when the focus is on an other object ... How can I listen for any keypress event regardless of the focus?

Comment: what do you mean by "an other object" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3 capture keypress regardless of the current focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011837/as3-capture-keypress-regardless-of-the-current-focus)

Comment: If you wish to elaborate your question, you can always edit it, don't add another one.

Comment: i'm sorry for the double post, somthing was strange withi this one ... it lost it's answers ... very strange ... and because the question was not specific enough, i made an other one ...

Answer (score 0):

try to hang keyboard event on `stage`