# AS3 capture keypress regardless of the current focus?

Tags: actionscript-3, focus, keypress

When I add a keypress event listener to the stage, it does not fire when the focus is on another object. How can I listen for any keypress event regardless of the focus?

Just setting the `useCapture` parameter to `true` does not work . I think it's because no event is bubbled up if I do not add a listener to every object on the stage.

Do I really have to add an eventlistener to every object to capture a keypress event regardless of the current focused object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you add your keyEventListener to the stage and then in functions where the focus is changed add the code:

stage.focus = stage

it might work.

Comment: thx ... yes this is a possibility ... but then i always have to set the focus to the stage ... thats seems extreme for me ...